# How to shutdown the UDC (usage data collection) from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to shutdown the UDC. It's very heavy for my pc. I already uncheck the "Enable Capture" checkbox but I have the feeling that it stay enable in the background. It constantly ask me the user and password of the proxy. I do not want an eclipse always trying to connect to internet and doing background procesing that I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Preferences -> Usage Data Collector -> Preview page where you can add filters.

If you want to be sure it doesn't run at all, the simplest thing might be to just remove `org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.*` from the plugins directory.

Comment: This is the only way to do disable UDC if you have multiple workspaces (say one per major project?). Disabling is a per-workspace setting and un-installing in eclipse rarely seems to work.

Comment: The remove filter button is always disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the capture, it shouldn't be attempting to connect. Are there any messages from the UDC in your workspace/.metadata/.log file?

Are there any files in your workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.recording directory? More specifically, are there any files there that have recent modified dates?

There is actually a bug open on the UDC complaining that it doesn't use the proxy service, so I'm pretty sure that it's not the UDC that's asking for that information. Could it maybe be Mylyn that's trying to connect to something?

Answer (score 0):

In 3.5 (Galileo) in the preferences there is a group named Usage Data Collector. In that category you can find a checkbox to turn off the data capture. There was a similar option in 3.4 (Ganymede), but it is not open in my computer.

Or you can try using P2 to completely uninstall the plugin. It won't harm anything.

Comment: "try using P2 to completely uninstall the plugin". How is that? I look in Help -> Software Update but uninstall the plugin is disable.

Comment: Sometimes it is disabled the uninstall if multiple plug-ins are selected. Try selecting only the UDC plug-in. If that does not help, I have not got an idea.
It works on my Galileo version as expected.